# How to set /clr:nostdlib in vs 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, compiler-options, mscorlib

I am trying to add /clr:nostdlib in my vs 2012 c# project because I want to use the System.Core of dotnet 4.0 as explained at http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/750762/problems-building-after-installing-vs-2012-rc

Now I am getting "Error 1 Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported" error in vs 2012. Can anybody show me how to do it step by step.